# Power Q: how to add conditional col and split based on length if another col contains text of same col

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, m

In power Q: creating a custom col based on condition:
If col A contains text of col b then split col A starting at the position of the length of ColumB

example: col A is MyMothersBasement123 and col B is MyMothersBase
col c would =  ment123

Somthing along the lines of :
 `if Text.Contains([ColumnA], [ColumnB]) then SplitTextByPositions({length of ColumB}) else [ColumnA]`

Comment: what does it mean to split column A by a length?  If column A was "ABCDEFGH IJKL MNO PQ" how do you split that by a number like 5 ? Into multiple columns of length 5? Something else

Comment: example: col A is MyMothersBasement123 and col B is MyMothersBase col c= ment123 @horseyride

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

add column .. custom column ...

```
= try Text.Split([Column1],[Column2]){1} otherwise [Column1]
```

or

```
= try Text.Replace([Column1],[Column2],"") otherwise [Column1]
```

Comment: Thank you, what does the {1} represent?

Comment: {1} = the second part of the array, so in this case, the part after the text we are splitting on

Answer (score 2):

You could also try

```
Text.AfterDelimiter([Column1], [Column2])
```

as long as [Column2] isn't blank.

You can use `try ... otherwise` to cover that situation.

```
try Text.AfterDelimiter([Column1], [Column2]) otherwise ""
```